# display:none; does not work with google maps

Tags: html

I have added a loader in my webpage which also contains GoogleMaps. When the page is loading, I use display: none; to hide the contents of the page when it is loading. display:none makes google maps to only display the canvas after the page is loaded and shown in block. Please help.
 The code is:

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0; background-color: white;">

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
```

I tried adding

```
display: block;
```

after the above line of code. The code is

```html
<div style="display:block;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
```

and it still didn't work

myFunction contains

```js
var myVar;
function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 1500);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: You missed to add your code..

Comment: There you bro. Just added the code snippet. Help if you have any solution

Comment: What do you have in myFunction()? Can you post it as well?

Comment: Javascript is added. I load the page using a package named pace.min.js and i am using bootstrap